# How to export contact list from gnome contacts

Tags: contacts, gnome

Gnome-contacts stores the contact in a file called contacts.db, that lives in
.local/share/evolution/addressbook

I can find no way to either:

1. export the contact list to something any other contacts program (kontact, communicator, etc) can import.
   or
2. import that contacts.db file into any other contacts program.

sqlitebrowser can read it, but the resulting csv file is corrupt and I cannot import it properly (eg, the phone numbers are not properly displayed or saved).

The following link
https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/exporting-data-contacts.html.en
Says to use File>Save Address Book as... but gnome contacts has no File menu (at least on my machine, version 3.38.1

Does anyone know how to export or convert that contacts.db file to vCard, or alternatively, something that  can import it properly?

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, but there are probably better ways. Here it is:

1. Open the contacts.db file using sqlitebrowser. The table has one column called vcard.
2. Exported the table as csv.
3. Open in librecalc. Select the column whose heading is vcard.
4. Copy and paste to a new text document. Save as .txt file.
5. Change suffix of saved file to .vcf
6. Import with kontact (probably can be by anything that accepted vCard).

Comment: So after messing around with this  for way too long, I found that in fact evolution reads the contacts.db info, and somehow I did not see it. Evolution can then export the list as vCard.

Comment: A less covoluted approach: `sqlite3 contacts.db "select vcard from folder_id" > contacts.vcf`